# Error with using @ComponentScan on multiple packages in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

Here's my issue--I have a service that relies on an external library. I was trying to autowire the service so I can use it but was not able to

```
import org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenService;

public class SimpleService {

   @Autowired
   private TokenService keycloakTokenSvc; // Could not autowire, no beans of type 'TokenService' found
 
   public void execute() {
       keyCloakTokenSvc.doSomething();
   }
   

}
```

I then added this to my SpringBootApplication and got it working:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.keycloak.admin.client.token"})
public MyApp {}
```

Sweet -- all good now, right? Nope. It seems like this overrides some of my auto configuraitons like my security config, so I was no longer to make RESTful requests to my application while it was running. I then did this next:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.keycloak.admin.client.token", "com.project.pkg"})
public MyApp {}
```

Still nothing. I get the same error as before:

```
Field keycloakTokenSvc in com.mark43.jms.services.TokenRefreshService required a bean of type 'org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenService' in your configuration.
```

I'm new to Spring Boot so not sure what to do here. Is there a way to use the `TokenService` without Autowiring? Is there a way to scan both packages?

Comment: It's a package outside my project, I can't annotate it. Are you only able to use annotated services?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need to create a `TokenService` bean as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class TokenConfig {
    @Bean
    public TokenService tokenService() {
        return new TokenService();  // Or whatever you need to instantiate it
    }
}
```

This will register a `TokenService` object as a Spring-managed bean so that it can be autowired into `SimpleService`.

Comment: I think I just improperly understood then. I'm not able to instantiate it since it's an interface.

Comment: This will not work. TokenService is just an interface and you can't create a reference on an an interface with new keyword without knowing the implementing class

Comment: Well, if `TokenService` is an interface then you need an implementation of such an interface. Do you have one? Does Keycloak provide one?